# vagrant-librarian-chef requires ruby version >= 2.0 public_suffix in ubuntu

Tags: ruby, vagrant, ubuntu-14.04

I try to run following command:
`vagrant plugin install vagrant-librarian-chef`

```
Installing the 'vagrant-librarian-chef' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:388:in `ensure_required_ruby_version_met': public_suffix requires Ruby version >= 2.0. (Gem::InstallError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:156:in `install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:297:in `block in install'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `each_with_index'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:270:in `install'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:65:in `block in call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:42:in `block in with_environment'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/user_interaction.rb:40:in `use_ui'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/gem_helper.rb:41:in `with_environment'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/install_gem.rb:52:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/action/bundler_check.rb:20:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/action/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/base.rb:17:in `action'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/install.rb:27:in `execute'
    from /usr/share/vagrant/plugins/commands/plugin/command/root.rb:56:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/cli.rb:38:in `execute'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/vagrant/environment.rb:484:in `cli'
    from /usr/bin/vagrant:127:in `<main>'
```

I am trying this on Ubuntu 14.04
I have been able to sucessfully install the following vagrant plugins:

1. vagrant-vbguest
2. vagrant-omnibus
3. vagrant-triggers
4. vagrant-hostmanager

Comment: As the error message states, your 1.9.3 Ruby on Ubuntu 14.04 is too old for this. Unfortunately, given the situation (installing a Vagrant plugin) your options for using rvm or rbenv are limited. Also, I couldn't really see you using Vagrant to install plugins for Vagrant. You basically need to upgrade to a more modern OS. Maybe try installing the last version of this plugin that supported 1.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can read there, you are using `ruby 1.9.1` and the error message is that you need at least `ruby 2.0` for that plugin.

Try updating `ruby` to a newer version. Also try using a tool like `rbenv` to manage multiple ruby versions, in case you need `ruby 1.9.1` for future projects.